# Outlook Appointment c#

Tags: c#, outlook, ldap

I'm trying to create an outlook appointment that goes directly into the users calendar and have responses go to a different email address.

Is this possible using and `LDAP` query? If not, what are my best options?

Thanks
Sp

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addAppointments(String subject,String body,DateTime startTime,DateTime endTime,String location) 
{
    Appointment app = new Appointment(_service);
    app.Subject = subject;
    app.Body = body;
    app.Start = startTime;
    app.End = endTime;
    app.Location = location;

    //DayOfTheWeek[] days = new DayOfTheWeek[] { DayOfTheWeek.Saturday };
    //app.Recurrence = new Recurrence.WeeklyPattern(app.Start.Date, 1, days);
    //app.Recurrence.StartDate = app.Start.Date;
    //app.Recurrence.NumberOfOccurrences = 3;

    app.Save();
}
```

This method can be used to add an appointment. Using Outlook api.

This link will also help.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/7ae6d938-a64f-4c27-95ba-435f84da236f

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do this using LDAP. You probably want to get hold of the Exchange Web Services assembly (Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices) which wraps the exchange server web service API and allows you to easily "do stuff" in exchange.

e.g. Example code to get appointments:

```
var service = new ExchangeService { UseDefaultCredentials = true };
service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress);

// Set the calendar view to use
var view = new CalendarView(startDate, endDate);

// Get the target folder ID using the email address
var folder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(emailAddress));

// Get the appointments
var response = service.FindAppointments(folder, view);
```

edit:

And to create one - (using some of the above code to get the service instance):

```
var apt = new Appointment(service);
apt.Start = DateTime.Now;
// Do other stuff
apt.Save();
```